# How to fill with color an area of a shape created with the pen tool in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to fill with colors each square inside the cube I drew with the pen tool. I made a custom grid and finally came up with the following shape:

[image]

The problem, is that I cannot find a way to color each part of this cube, and even fill parts if I merge this cube for another, here is an example:

[image]

Basically, fill those closed areas with a color or gradient. It is not letting me.

How can I achieve filling with color those areas with a different color each?

Answer (score 1):

- Select All
- Grab the **Live Paint Bucket** Tool
- Click each side
- Expand the Live Paint Object
- Select and fill the sides with whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you have a collection of lines rather than shapes which can be filled.
You can use the Live Paint Tool as in the other answer. I think I would use the Shapebuilder Tool for this:

Select all your lines

Go to Shapebuilder Tool in the Tool Palette (or press Shift + M)

Click inside each shape you want to color

Select each of your shapes and add color fill as you please

[image]